# Quick Conditional Formatting for rows with same Data in a Column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have lots of data, basically like this:

```
Name    Data    Date        ...
Groucho 123     06/23/2018
Harpo   321     05/02/2018
Chico   1239    04/17/2018
Zeppo   2938    12/03/2018
Groucho 123098  11/27/2018
Zeppo   29381   07/03/2018
...
```

I'd like each row with the same `Name` to be highlighted some color. (I don't particularly care what color if that makes it easier).

So the results would look like this:
[image]
(Note: The whole row can be highlighted, or just the row within the "table". Whatever would work is fine with me)

Is there a quick(er) way I can do this? I'd rather not have to enter a bunch of rules like `=$A2="Groucho"` then set a format, then new rule `=$A2="Chico"`, and set a color, etc. as I could have dozens of names in Column A and manually creating a rule for each is rather time consuming.

I'm open to a VBA option, but prefer a built-in solution if available!

Comment: Initial research doesn't bring up many baked-in options, but I'm working through a VBA option. Do you need to pick the colors, or are you ok with Excel automatically assigning colors?

Comment: @jrichall - In am totally fine with automatic colors - with the caveat that I don't want one Name to be say `RGB(0,0,0)` then another name being `RGB(10,0,0)` where you can't really discern.  I was also about to hop in VBA, and I was going to work that part by storing the colors I've chosen, and before setting the *next* color, make sure each `R`, `G`, and `B` value is at least X% different than one I've used.  Or if it's easier somehow, I'm **totally fine** with choosing myself.

Comment: @jrichall maybe store a bunch in a list, [using RGB()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25201431) and just loop through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a VBA Solution:

```
Sub conditional_format_by_name()
Dim rng As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Please select the range to Format", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0
If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

rng.Select 'So the user can see the range selected, to know which column they want in the next step

Dim primaryCol As Long
primaryCol = InputBox("Now, **within that range**, which column number do you want to use as the basis for matches?")
rng.Columns(1).Select

Dim primaryList() As Variant
primaryList = rng.Columns(1).Value

Dim unique(), i As Long
unique = removeDuplicates(primaryList)
For i = LBound(unique) To UBound(unique)
    Debug.Print "Adding condition for: " & unique(i)
    rng.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rng.Cells(1).Address(0) & "=""" & unique(i) & """"
    With rng.FormatConditions(1 + i).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = ColorRandomizer()
        .TintAndShade = 0.5
    End With
    rng.FormatConditions(1 + i).StopIfTrue = False
Next i
End Sub

Function removeDuplicates(ByVal myArray As Variant) As Variant
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/43102816/4650297
Dim d As Object
Dim v As Variant 'Value for function
Dim outputArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For i = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    d(myArray(i, 1)) = 1
Next i
i = 0
For Each v In d.Keys()
    ReDim Preserve outputArray(0 To i)
    outputArray(i) = v
    i = i + 1
Next v
removeDuplicates = outputArray
End Function
Function ColorRandomizer() As Long
'https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/tip-tricks-code/102242-rgb-color-random
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long
Randomize
i = Int((255 * Rnd) + 1)
m = Int((255 * Rnd) + 1)
k = Int((255 * Rnd) + 1)
ColorRandomizer = RGB(i, m, k)
End Function
```

[image]

Issues: The colors for each group may be close to one another, and/or be too dark to be effective.  Will think about how to work around this.  May have to return `R`, `G`, and `B` values and check for those I've used before, and if the new values are within say 25% of an already used value, generate a new number?

Comment: This is the direction I was beginning to build out as well, @BruceWayne, but your vba is much more robust. I was utilizing the `Interior.ColorIndex` feature, which definitely uses much different colors, but they're Excel's baked in ones and are pretty ugly.